# iOS SWIFT - WebRTC change from Front Camera to back Camera

Tags: ios, swift3, webrtc

WebRTC video by default uses Front Camera, which works fine. However, i need to switch it to back camera, and i have not been able to find any code to do that. 
Which part do i need to edit? 
Is it the localView or localVideoTrack or capturer?

Comment: Are you using webrtc library or openwebrtc library ?

Comment: @DuraiAmuthan.H I'm using libjingle_peerconnection pod

Comment: Try removing the existing AVCameraInput from the AVCaptureSession and then adding new AVCameraInput to the AVCaptureSession with AVCaptureDevicePositionBack

Comment: have you found the solution for the question you asked.

Answer (score 4):

**Swift 3.0**

Peer connection can have only one 'RTCVideoTrack' for sending video stream.

At first, for change camera front/back you must remove current video track on peer connection. 
After then, you create new 'RTCVideoTrack' on camera which you need, and set this for peer connection.

I used this methods.

```
func swapCameraToFront() {
    let localStream: RTCMediaStream? = peerConnection?.localStreams.first as? RTCMediaStream
    localStream?.removeVideoTrack(localStream?.videoTracks.first as! RTCVideoTrack)
    let localVideoTrack: RTCVideoTrack? = createLocalVideoTrack()
    if localVideoTrack != nil {
        localStream?.addVideoTrack(localVideoTrack)
        delegate?.appClient(self, didReceiveLocalVideoTrack: localVideoTrack!)
    }
    peerConnection?.remove(localStream)
    peerConnection?.add(localStream)
}

func swapCameraToBack() {
    let localStream: RTCMediaStream? = peerConnection?.localStreams.first as? RTCMediaStream
    localStream?.removeVideoTrack(localStream?.videoTracks.first as! RTCVideoTrack)
    let localVideoTrack: RTCVideoTrack? = createLocalVideoTrackBackCamera()
    if localVideoTrack != nil {
        localStream?.addVideoTrack(localVideoTrack)
        delegate?.appClient(self, didReceiveLocalVideoTrack: localVideoTrack!)
    }
    peerConnection?.remove(localStream)
    peerConnection?.add(localStream)
}
```

Comment: While this may answer the question, it is better to explain the essential parts of the answer and possibly what was the problem with OPs code.

Comment: Can you please add how you generate video track with back camera. Implementation of `createLocalVideoTrackBackCamera ` method.

Comment: Adding a new stream to the peer connection will add some delay to your video. Just add/remove the video track from the local stream.

Answer (score 2):

As of now I only have the answer in `Objective C` language in regard to **Ankit**'s comment below. I will convert it into `Swift` after some time.

You can check the below code

```
- (RTCVideoTrack *)createLocalVideoTrack {

    RTCVideoTrack *localVideoTrack = nil; 
    NSString *cameraID = nil; 
    for (AVCaptureDevice *captureDevice in [AVCaptureDevice devicesWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo]) {
       if (captureDevice.position == AVCaptureDevicePositionFront) { 
        cameraID = [captureDevice localizedName]; break;
       }
    }

    RTCVideoCapturer *capturer = [RTCVideoCapturer capturerWithDeviceName:cameraID]; 
    RTCMediaConstraints *mediaConstraints = [self defaultMediaStreamConstraints]; 
    RTCVideoSource *videoSource = [_factory videoSourceWithCapturer:capturer constraints:mediaConstraints]; 
    localVideoTrack = [_factory videoTrackWithID:@"ARDAMSv0" source:videoSource];

       return localVideoTrack; 
   }

- (RTCVideoTrack *)createLocalVideoTrackBackCamera {
    RTCVideoTrack *localVideoTrack = nil;
    //AVCaptureDevicePositionFront
    NSString *cameraID = nil;
    for (AVCaptureDevice *captureDevice in [AVCaptureDevice devicesWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo]) {
     if (captureDevice.position == AVCaptureDevicePositionBack) {
         cameraID = [captureDevice localizedName];
         break;
     }
    }

  RTCVideoCapturer *capturer = [RTCVideoCapturer capturerWithDeviceName:cameraID];
  RTCMediaConstraints *mediaConstraints = [self defaultMediaStreamConstraints];
  RTCVideoSource *videoSource = [_factory videoSourceWithCapturer:capturer constraints:mediaConstraints];
  localVideoTrack = [_factory videoTrackWithID:@"ARDAMSv0" source:videoSource];

  return localVideoTrack;
}
```

Comment: This answer has some severe formatting issues. Please edit and format your answer, otherwise I will have to flag it unfortenately.

Answer (score 1):

If you decide to use official Google build here the explanation:

First, you must configure your camera before call start, best place to do that in `ARDVideoCallViewDelegate` in method `didCreateLocalCapturer`

```
- (void)startCapture:(void (^)(BOOL succeeded))completionHandler {
    AVCaptureDevicePosition position = _usingFrontCamera ? AVCaptureDevicePositionFront : AVCaptureDevicePositionBack;
    __weak AVCaptureDevice *device = [self findDeviceForPosition:position];
    if ([device lockForConfiguration:nil]) {
        if ([device isFocusPointOfInterestSupported]) {
            [device setFocusModeLockedWithLensPosition:0.9 completionHandler: nil];
        }
    }
    AVCaptureDeviceFormat *format = [self selectFormatForDevice:device];
    if (format == nil) {
        RTCLogError(@"No valid formats for device %@", device);
        NSAssert(NO, @"");
        return;
    }
    NSInteger fps = [self selectFpsForFormat:format];
    [_capturer startCaptureWithDevice: device
                               format: format
                                  fps:fps completionHandler:^(NSError *    error) {
                                      NSLog(@"%@",error);
                                      if (error == nil) {
                                          completionHandler(true);
                                      }
                                  }];
}
```

Don't forget enabling capture device is asynchronous, sometime better to use completion to be sure everything done as expected.

Comment: you can check it in official WERTC repo, or here https://github.com/WebKit/webkit/blob/master/Source/ThirdParty/libwebrtc/Source/webrtc/examples/objc/AppRTCMobile/ARDCaptureController.m

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure which chrome version you are using for webrtc but with v54 and above there is "bool" property called "useBackCamera" in RTCAVFoundationVideoSource class. You can make use of this property to switch between front/back camera.

Comment: Header file: https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/third_party/webrtc/sdk/objc/Framework/Headers/WebRTC/RTCAVFoundationVideoSource.h?rcl=c0a0f8d5f2d5b837b4c6ea447b0cdce86723e0d6&l=46

Comment: Quiestion has no relation to Chrome or any browser. It is about native iOS development

Comment: @ModoLtunzher By chrome version, i meant webrtc libjingle version. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4.0 & 'GoogleWebRTC' : '1.1.20913'**

**RTCAVFoundationVideoSource** class has a property named **useBackCamera** that can be used for switching the camera used.

```
@interface RTCAVFoundationVideoSource : RTCVideoSource

- (instancetype)init NS_UNAVAILABLE;

/**
* Calling this function will cause frames to be scaled down to the
* requested resolution. Also, frames will be cropped to match the
* requested aspect ratio, and frames will be dropped to match the
* requested fps. The requested aspect ratio is orientation agnostic and
* will be adjusted to maintain the input orientation, so it doesn't
* matter if e.g. 1280x720 or 720x1280 is requested.
*/
- (void)adaptOutputFormatToWidth:(int)width height:(int)height fps:(int)fps;

/** Returns whether rear-facing camera is available for use. */
@property(nonatomic, readonly) BOOL canUseBackCamera;

/** Switches the camera being used (either front or back). */
@property(nonatomic, assign) BOOL useBackCamera;

/** Returns the active capture session. */
@property(nonatomic, readonly) AVCaptureSession *captureSession;
```

Below is the implementation for switching camera.

```
var useBackCamera: Bool = false

func switchCamera() {
    useBackCamera = !useBackCamera
    self.switchCamera(useBackCamera: useBackCamera)
}

private func switchCamera(useBackCamera: Bool) -> Void {

    let localStream = peerConnection?.localStreams.first

    if let videoTrack = localStream?.videoTracks.first {
        localStream?.removeVideoTrack(videoTrack)
    }

    let localVideoTrack = createLocalVideoTrack(useBackCamera: useBackCamera)
    localStream?.addVideoTrack(localVideoTrack)

    self.delegate?.webRTCClientDidAddLocal(videoTrack: localVideoTrack)

    if let ls = localStream {
        peerConnection?.remove(ls)
        peerConnection?.add(ls)
    }
}

func createLocalVideoTrack(useBackCamera: Bool) -> RTCVideoTrack {

    let videoSource = self.factory.avFoundationVideoSource(with: self.constraints)
    videoSource.useBackCamera = useBackCamera
    let videoTrack = self.factory.videoTrack(with: videoSource, trackId: "video")
    return videoTrack
}
```

Comment: This is not valid anymore. RTCAVFoundationVideoSource has been deprecated https://codereview.chromium.org/2987143003/

Answer (score 0):

In the current version of **WebRTC**, RTCAVFoundationVideoSource has been [deprecated](http://codereview.chromium.org/2987143003) and replaced with a
generic RTCVideoSource combined with an RTCVideoCapturer implementation.

In order to switch the camera I'm doing this:

```
- (void)switchCameraToPosition:(AVCaptureDevicePosition)position completionHandler:(void (^)(void))completionHandler {
    if (self.cameraPosition != position) {
      RTCMediaStream *localStream = self.peerConnection.localStreams.firstObject;
      [localStream removeVideoTrack:self.localVideoTrack];
      //[self.peerConnection removeStream:localStream];
      self.localVideoTrack = [self createVideoTrack];

      [self startCaptureLocalVideoWithPosition:position completionHandler:^{
        [localStream addVideoTrack:self.localVideoTrack];
        //[self.peerConnection addStream:localStream];
        if (completionHandler) {
            completionHandler();
        }
      }];

      self.cameraPosition = position;
    }
}
```

Take a look at the commented lines, If you start adding/removing the stream from the peer connection it will cause a delay in the video connection.

**I'm using GoogleWebRTC-1.1.25102**

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who still has an issue regarding this topic.
Besides RTCAVFoundationVideoSource being deprecated one of the other solutions above will do the job.

This is how I solved it:

```
try? targetDevice?.lockForConfiguration()
...
let dataOutput = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()
dataOutput.videoSettings = [(kCVPixelBufferWidthKey as NSString) : NSNumber(value: 480 as UInt32),
                            (kCVPixelBufferHeightKey as NSString) : NSNumber(value: 640 as UInt32)] as [String : Any]
if (capturer.captureSession.canAddOutput(dataOutput) == true) {
    if capturer.captureSession.outputs.count > 1 {
        capturer.captureSession.removeOutput(capturer.captureSession.outputs.last!)
    }
    capturer.captureSession.addOutput(dataOutput)
}
...
capturer.startCapture(with: targetDevice!,
                            format: targetFormat!,
                            fps: 30)
```

Where:

- targetDevice is the preferred device (front or back)
- capturer is the RTCCameraVideoCapturer

Now, important in this example is the second if. Apparently if I do not remove the output that I aded initially to the captureSession, before I switch the camera, the stream will freeze both on the local device and the remote device as well. Important here is to always remove the last output, not the first one. I hope this will help someone.