# Wowza/WebRTC - how to re-negotiate video format on camera flip

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, webrtc, wowza

I followed some hints from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42712769/ios-swift-webrtc-change-from-front-camera-to-back-camera) to make camera flip from front to back while presenting/streaming via WebRTC on iOS. The flip itself works but when video track changes in `RTCMediaStream`, the `RTCPeerConnection` calls again `peerConnectionShouldNegotiate` delegate method. Here is my current implementation of it (it works on initial call for front camera video, but it fails when called for the second time when video flips):

```swift
func peerConnectionShouldNegotiate(_ peerConnection: RTCPeerConnection) {
        guard let stream = liveStream else {
            return
        }
        print("peerConnectionShouldNegotiate")
        peerConnection.offer(for: mediaConstraints) { (desc, err) in
            if let error = err {
                print("peerConnectionShouldNegotiate error", error)
            } else if let desc = desc {
                self.con?.setLocalDescription(desc, completionHandler: { (err) in
                    if let error = err {
                        print("set local desc error", error)
                    } else {
                        let message: [String: Any] = [
                            "direction": "publish",
                            "command": "sendOffer",
                            "streamInfo": [
                                "applicationName": stream.appName,
                                "streamName": stream.streamName,
                                "sessionId": self.sessionId
                            ],
                            "sdp": [
                                "type": RTCSessionDescription.string(for: desc.type),
                                "sdp": desc.sdp
                            ],
                            "userData": [
                                "param1": "value1"
                            ]
                        ]
                        let messageData = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: message, options: [])
                        let messageStr = String(data: messageData, encoding: .utf8)!
                        self.socket?.write(string: messageStr)
                    }
                })
            } else {
                print("this is a no no")
            }
        }
    }
```

The web-socket response from signaling server comes with error and message `Stream name is already in use: [my-stream-id]`

I don't know what kind of message I should send to Wowza's signaling server to just update video format in existing stream. It appears `sendOffer` tries to start a new steam. It's hard to find any documentation about this.

Answer (score 1):

Posting my solution here if somebody else gets the same issue, it took me several days of trial and error to come to a solution.

What I really needed was to just switch camera without re-negotiating `RTCPeerConnection`. I saw javascript examples where they switched the video track on `RTCRtpSender` but that didn't work on iOS, also the iOS framework didn't had `replaceVideoTrack` method which existed in browser's javascript WebRTC library.

My solution was to just update camera on the existing `RTCCameraVideoCapturer` and thus preserving **existing** `RTCVideoSource` and `RTCVideoTrack`.

My initial call to create video track is like this:

```swift
    func createVideoTrack() -> RTCVideoTrack? {
        let devices = RTCCameraVideoCapturer.captureDevices()
        guard
            let camera = selectedCamera(devices: devices)
        else {
            return nil
        }
        let source = rtcPCFactory.videoSource()
        let format = selectFormat(formats: camera.formats)
        let dims = CMVideoFormatDescriptionGetDimensions(format.formatDescription)
        if dims.width > dims.height {
            videoSize = CGSize(width: CGFloat(dims.height), height: CGFloat(dims.width))
        } else {
            videoSize = CGSize(width: CGFloat(dims.width), height: CGFloat(dims.height))
        }
        let fps = selectFrameRate(ranges: format.videoSupportedFrameRateRanges)
        source.adaptOutputFormat(toWidth: 512, height: 288, fps: Int32(fps))
        let videoTrack = rtcPCFactory.videoTrack(with: source, trackId: internalStreamId + "v0")

        let capturer = RTCCameraVideoCapturer(delegate: source)
        capturer.startCapture(with: camera, format: format, fps: Int(fps))
        
        cameraPreviewView.captureSession = capturer.captureSession
        videoCapturer = capturer
        return videoTrack
    }
```

which successfully negotiated peer connection and then on the flip of the camera I did this:

```swift
    func updateCapturerCamera() {
        let devices = RTCCameraVideoCapturer.captureDevices()
        guard
            let camera = selectedCamera(devices: devices),
            let capturer = videoCapturer
        else {
            return
        }
        let format = selectFormat(formats: camera.formats)
        let dims = CMVideoFormatDescriptionGetDimensions(format.formatDescription)
        if dims.width > dims.height {
            videoSize = CGSize(width: CGFloat(dims.height), height: CGFloat(dims.width))
        } else {
            videoSize = CGSize(width: CGFloat(dims.width), height: CGFloat(dims.height))
        }
        let fps = selectFrameRate(ranges: format.videoSupportedFrameRateRanges)
        capturer.startCapture(with: camera, format: format, fps: Int(fps))
    }
```

... and the camera flip worked as charm on live video stream without re-negotiating the connection.